# restoreStateWithCoder not firing in NSView

Tags: cocoa, nsview, restore

I have subclassed an nsview and want to implement the resume feature. Before i quit the application the encode code runs:

```
-(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
     [coder encodeObject:[NSValue valueWithRect:self.originalFrame] forKey:@"originalFrame"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}
```

When starting the application again , restoreStateWithCoder is never called ?

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem and found the solution in the [NSUserInterfaceItemIdentification protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsuserinterfaceitemidentification/1396829-identifier):

> Identifiers are used during window restoration operations to uniquely
> identify the windows of the application. You can set the value of this
> string programmatically or in Interface Builder. If you create an item
> in Interface Builder and do not set a value for this string, a unique
> value is created for the item when the nib file is loaded. **For
> programmatically created views, you typically set this value after
> creating the item but before adding it to a window.**

I did create my view programmatically, so there was no identifier set for it and the window restoration mechanism didn't call the view restoration methods.

Before adding your view to the window, you need to set an identifier like this:

```
_exampleView.identifier = @"ExampleIdentifier";
```

If your view then calls `[self invalidateRestorableState]`, the system will call `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder` at the appropriate time and everything works as expected.

Comment: encodeRestorableStateWithCoder is called. But restoreStateWithCoder is not called. I have set the identifier for the view.

Comment: Does the window that contains the view get restored properly?

Comment: yeah the size and frame get restored.

Comment: @Lextar Same problem here - identifier wasn't set for my `NSViewController` I've attempted to restore! Thanks a lot!!